# Express session getting cleared between routes

Tags: node.js, express, curl, express-session

I have below two routes in which I have used `express-session` to manage user session.

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    //all variables defined here
    if(usernm&&passwd){
        connection.query("select * from session where username=?;",[usernm],function(err,result){
            if(err) throw err;
            else if(result.length!=0){
                res.send("Already signed in with username "+usernm);            
            }   
            else{
            connection.query("select * from signup where username=? and passwd=?;",credentials, function(err1, result){
            if(err1) throw err1;
            if(result.length!=0)
            {
                req.session.loggedin=true;
                req.session.username=usernm;
                var sql1="insert into session values('"+usernm+"','"+req.sessionID+"');";
                connection.query(sql1,function(err, result){
                    if(err) throw err;
                    else{
                        console.log(req.sessionID);
                        res.send('Logged in successfully with username '+req.session.username);
                        }

            });
            }
            else{
            obj={'status':'error','message':'Incorrect Username and/or Password'};
            obj=JSON.stringify(obj);
            res.send(obj);  
            }
            
        });
    }               
        });
    }
});

app.get('/logout',(req,res)=>{
    var sessionId=req.sessionID;
    var username=req.session.username;
    console.log(sessionId,username);
    req.session.loggedin=false;
    req.session.username=null;
    req.session.destroy();
        connection.query("Delete from session where sessionID=? or username=?;",[sessionId,username],function(err,result){
        if(err) throw err;
        else{
        res.send("User signed out successfully!");  
    }

    });
});
```

I am using curl to test my api endpoints. So, the problem is that when I send a post http request to `login`, I get a `sessionID` on console. But when I hit `logout` using curl, the `sessionID` printed here is different from the one printed in `login` route, which means the sessionID gets changed in between the routes.
Also, the `console.log` in `logout` prints `req.session.username` as `undefined`, which it shouldn't do.

As far as I know, this problem relates to session data getting cleared between two page requests.

I wonder why it is happening. Please help me to find the reason of above behaviour so that I can go ahead with my application.

Thank You!